# coldfusion 9 check against multiple variables and any combination valid

Tags: coldfusion, boolean, operators

I have an if statement and I want to check against multiple variables, but I want any combination of the variables are valid.

```
<cfif var1 AND OR var2 AND OR var3>
   execute
<cfelse>
   NO
</cfif>
```

**Update from comments:**

The variables return boolean values

Comment: which variable values you want check against. add some more details.

Comment: What do the variables contain (strings, numbers, boolean, ...) and *specifically* what do you need to "check"? How are you defining "any combination of the variables are valid"?

Comment: I wish SO would require down-voters to leave a comment as to why.

Comment: Agreed. While I think it could have been a little more clear, it was not bad enough to warrant a down vote IMO.

Comment: I think the nature of the question comes from the fact that often in spoken language `OR` means what we would call `exclusive or`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you would just use `OR` and exclude using `AND` If `var1` `var2` or `var3` were true then your code would execute

If `var1` is a boolean then saying `var1` is accurate

If `var1` is a string you would check `len(trim(var1))`

If `var1` is a number you would check `var1 GT 0`

```
<cfif var1 OR var2 OR var3>
   execute
<cfelse>
   NO
</cfif>
```

Comment: Thanks Matt that works fine. The variables return Boolean values.